# Access to Request Header in Unity WebApi2 C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I want to create a `RegisterType` base on Request Header in Unity, C#.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<OrganizationServiceProxy>(new InjectionFactory(unityContainer =>
{
    var request = HttpContext.Current.Request; //Exception 'Request is not available in this context
    const string errorMessage = "Please add `CrmType` key to header to specify CRM type";
    var crmTypeString = request.Headers["CrmType"];
    .
    .
    .
    return new SOmeObject(crmTypeString );
}));
```

But the following exception occurred :
`Request is not available in this context`

How can web access to request header in Unity 5.2.0.

Comment: So, How can I register an instance an object needs a request header value? What is your solution?

Comment: I don't have one.  Your HttpContext object is not happy with the conditions you have provided it.  I've worked with HttpContext before, but I've never had this problem.

Comment: @MohammadDayyan `How can web access to request header in Unity 5.2.0.` by making sure you are in the context of a request when accessing that property

Comment: @Nosi How can I make sure about it?

Comment: Think `IHttpContextAccessor` from core but adapted to asp.net-web-api2+

Comment: @MohammadDayyan you're going to have to provide more details about the context under which your code is being used.

Comment: Where is `OrganizationServiceProxy` being accessed? because that determines when the container will resolve the type and try to access the context.

Comment: Also tightly coupling to `HttpContext` is going to cause a lot of problems. So figure out how to abstract that out.

Comment: @Nkosi I access it within controller constructor

Comment: Request is not available in controller constructor. Which explains the error. Defer access the request on till within a controller action

Comment: @MohammadDayyan show how the `SomeObject` example makes use of the injected dependency. It should help identify what needs to be refactored to make the code more flexible.

Comment: Also update the question with all the relevant details you shared in the comments that should have been in the original question.